# cannot make http.post request to nodejs using angularjs in amazow aws server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-ec2

*my nodejs application was running successfully on digital ocean server but it post request stop working once i deploy it to amazon aws server*

### my angular js http.post function

$http.post(base+url,
                            form,
                            {

```
                            method : 'POST',
                            crossDomain: true,
                            json: true, 
                            headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}


                    }
```

it it was running successfully on digital ocean server

#### i also try

$http.post(base+url,
                            form,
                            {

```
                            method : 'POST',
                            crossDomain: true,
                            json: true, 
                            headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}


                    }
```

### i am setting header in nodejs using

app.use(function (req, res, next) {

```
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

    // add details of what is allowed in HTTP request headers to the response headers

    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);

   // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');

   // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false);

    res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '586400');


    // the next() function continues execution and will move onto the requested URL/URI

    next();
```

});

### but once i deploy the project in amazon aws server it stops working cannot make any post requeat

i am new in amazon please help me to run my code in amazon aws as it was running in digital ocean

## my post route

```
router.route('/login')
```

.post(function (req, res) {

```
// was post method
//req.body      = req.query;

var async       = require('async');
var utils       = require('utility/utils'),
    db_query    = require('db_query/query'),
    constant    = require("config/constant");
var response_data = {};

async.series([
    function(callback) {
        var validate = require('utility/validate');
        validate.validateSignin(req,res,function(){
            callback();
        })
    },
    function(callback){
        var crypto      = require('crypto'),
            userName    = req.body.username,

            password    = req.body.password;
        var selection   = '*',
            table       = constant.USER_MASTER_TABLE;
        var condition   = [{
                            "name"  : "userName",
                            "type"  : constant.VARCHAR50,
                            "value" : userName
                        },{
                            "name"  : "userPwd",
                            "type"  : constant.VARCHAR50,
                            "value" : password
                        }];
        db_query.selectFromDb(req,res,condition,selection,table,response_data,function(){
            if(response_data.details.length>0)
            {
                if(response_data.details[0].UserActiveStatus == constant.ACTIVE_STATUS)
                {
                    response_data.user_details =  response_data.details;
                    callback();
                }
                else
                {
                    response_data.success = false;
                    response_data.message = "Please Enter active Username and Password.";
                    res.status(203).send({response_data});
                }
            }
            else
            {
                response_data.success = false;
                response_data.message = "Please Enter valid Username and Password.";
                res.status(203).send({response_data});
            }
        })
    },
    function(callback)
    {
        utils.createAuthentication(res,res,response_data.details[0],function(token){
            response_data.token = token;
            callback();
        })
    },
    function(callback)
    {
        var table     = constant.USER_MASTER_TABLE;
        var fieldlist   = [
             {
                "name"  : "userLastLogin",
                "type"  : constant.DATE_TIME,
                "varname" : "SYSDATETIME()",
                "value" : null
            }];
        var condition   = [{
                "name"  : "userId",
                "type"  : constant.SMINT,
                "value" : response_data.details[0].userId
            }];
        db_query.updateToDb(req,res,condition,fieldlist,table,response_data,function(){
            callback();
        });
    }

    ],function(err) {
        response_data.success = true;
        response_data.message = "successfully login!";
        res.status(200).send({response_data});
    });
});
```

Comment: Your security group is preventing access from outside of the AWS network.
Edit your security group to allow access to the port used by your app

Comment: hello saneesh i am totally new to amazon aws ec2 . it would be kind of you if you can tell me possible solution for this or what i have to do to overcome this problem

Answer (score 1):

1) Left panel -> (In Network and Security) -> Security groups

2) Select the security group for your current instance.

3) In the Actions Dropdown -> Click Edit inbound rules.

4) Select Type as "All Traffic" and source as "Anywhere".

5) Click Save.

That should do it.

Comment: thanks but i had done this earlier but not get any success

Comment: can you ping your server ?

Comment: That is problem with your code not AWS. post your request code here

Comment: my aws server is getting ping   ec2-35-161-211-221.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com   i had uploaded my api route please see it what wrong i am  doing

Comment: The code you posted is working fine since its the server side one, because u get response from postman. Check the code that you use to connect to the API thats where the culprit is

Comment: thank you very much saneesh   my problem was    i was using res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');       i replace it with       res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'application/json');                it start working thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

```
## my problem was i was using ##
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*'); 
##i replace it with ##

res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'application/json'); 

it start working
```